# eclipse error cannot find -l/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/libcrypto

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, openssl, aes

I got an error mentioned above when trying to build the application. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and i am coding in C. i installed library by "sudo apt-get install openssl" command.

```
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
AES_encrypt(originalString, enc_out, &enc_key);
```

Above codes gives an error "undefined reference" when i simply put the code and build. If i try to add a library from project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross GCC Linker->Libraries, it gives the error mentioned in the header.

i tried to create symbolic link or directly copy folder to gcc folder but does not work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

i found that problem is about adding libraries. I added ssl and crypto as well(which i add newly) from Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross GCC Linker->Libraries and also related path.